# Access to register of unclocked peripheral at 0x40000000 cause BUS_FAULT [U2_CM3CORE]

Tags: stm32, keil, stm32cubeide, stm32f1

I'm working with STM32F103C6, HCSR-04 Ultrasonic sensor and LCD display.
I simulate that in Proteus Professional 8, when I activate Timer 2 in STM32, there are big problems with frequency, frequency of LCD display = 250kHz, frequency of STM32 = 36MHz. In this state, program will eject this message "Access to register of unclocked peripheral at 0x40000000 cause BUS_FAULT [U2_CM3CORE]" more than 1000 times, and then program will crash.

If I increase frequency of STM32 in Proteus then LCD display shows nothing. How to fix this problem?

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2022 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "lcd_txt.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#include "HCSR04.h"
/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#define HCSR04_SENSOR1 8
uint16_t TRIG_Ticks = 0;
uint16_t LCD_Ticks = 0;
float Distance = 0.0;
char TEXT[16] = {0};
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
#define usTIM   TIM1

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
I2C_HandleTypeDef hi2c1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
void usDelay(uint32_t uSec);

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    uint32_t numTicks = 0;
    
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_I2C1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    lcd_init();
    lcd_puts(1,0, (int8_t*)"test");
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
    HCSR04_Init(HCSR04_SENSOR1, &htim2);
    lcd_puts(0,0, (int8_t*)"test");

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */
        Distance = HCSR04_Read(HCSR04_SENSOR1);
    sprintf(TEXT, "Dist= %.2f cm", Distance);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    HCSR04_TMR_IC_ISR(htim);
}
 
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
    HCSR04_TMR_OVF_ISR(htim);
}
 
void SysTick_CallBack(void)
{
    TRIG_Ticks++;
    LCD_Ticks++;
    if(TRIG_Ticks >= 15) // Each 15msec
    {
        HCSR04_Trigger(HCSR04_SENSOR1);
        TRIG_Ticks = 0;
    }
    if(LCD_Ticks >= 200) // Each 200msec
    {
        lcd_clear();
        lcd_puts(0,0, (int8_t*)TEXT);
        LCD_Ticks = 0;
    }
}
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief I2C1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.ClockSpeed = 100000;
  hi2c1.Init.DutyCycle = I2C_DUTYCYCLE_2;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 0;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigIC.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfigIC.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfigIC.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfigIC.ICFilter = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 1 */
  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 115200;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13
                          |GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB10 PB11 PB12 PB13
                           PB14 PB15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13
                          |GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void usDelay(uint32_t uSec)
{
    if(uSec < 2) uSec = 2;
    usTIM->ARR = uSec - 1;  /*sets the value in the auto-reload register*/
    usTIM->EGR = 1;             /*Re-initialises the timer*/
    usTIM->SR &= ~1;        //Resets the flag
    usTIM->CR1 |= 1;        //Enables the counter
    while((usTIM->SR&0x0001) != 1);
    usTIM->SR &= ~(0x0001);
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

Comment: Sounds like the error message is telling you exactly what to do. You need to set the TIM2EN bit in RCC_APB1ENR to enable the clock for TIM2.

Comment: @pmacfarlane how to do it, sorry for asking, I'm beginner in this area

Comment: Actually, I suspect that you don't need to do that, now that you have added your code. I suspect one of your functions (e.g. SysTick_Callback()) is accessing TIM2 before it has had its clock enabled. Your config for TIM2 seems odd - a period of zero? I'd say you're trying to do too much at the same time here. Get one thing working first, then move on to the next thing.

Comment: I commented these lines, everything that have some type of connection with HCSR 04 sensor, I think the problem is in function MX_TIM2_Init()

Comment: You should have a file called Core/Src/stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c. It should contain a function called HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(), and that function should call __HAL_RCC_TIM2_CLK_ENABLE(). Can you verify that?

Comment: Can you run it in a debugger and get the stack backtrace when the error occurs?

Comment: check it on the real hardware. Do not waste your time using simulators

Comment: proteus tag  is  wrong (was as I ave removed it)

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem happened to me too, the error that I wrote:

> Access to register of unclocked peripheral at 0x40010814 cause BUS_FAULT [U1_CM3CORE]

My solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in Proteus, tray to write 72MHz in Crystal Frequency in the window of your microcontroler in proteus simulation, it would work
hard luck